# RoutedCommand in ContextMenu in UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, routed-commands

**Situation:**

I have a static `RoutedCommand` defined like this:

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand GrowingOperation = new RoutedCommand("GrowingOperation", typeof(GrowingDisplay));
}
```

In my `MyUserControl.xaml` I define the command like this:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.GrowingOperation}"
                    Executed="GrowingOperationExecuted"
                    CanExecute="GrowingOperationCanExecute"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

And then use it like this in my `ContextMenu` of my `MyUserControl`:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="GrowingContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Grow"
                      Command="{x:Static local:Commands.GrowingOperation}"
                      CommandParameter="grow"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

**Issue:**

The `ContextMenu` appears, but neither the `GrowingOperationExecuted` nor the `GrowingOperationCanExecute` get called. Neither do I get any exception when opening the `ContextMenu`.

The open `ContextMenu` looks like this:
[image]

It seems to be enabled, but there is absolute no interaction, not even a hover animation.
Where is the error here?

**EDIT:**

Here the implementation of the command methods:

```
    private void GrowingOperationExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("ExecutedRoutedEventArgs must contain parameter.");
        var task = e.Parameter.ToString().ToLower();
        switch (task)
        {
            case "grow":
                Growing.SpeedUpGrowing();
                break;
            default:
                throw  new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private void GrowingOperationCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("ExecutedRoutedEventArgs must contain parameter.");
        var task = e.Parameter.ToString().ToLower();
        switch (task)
        {
            case "grow":
                e.CanExecute = Growing.CanSpeedUpGrowing();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

The constructor of my `MyUserControl`:

```
public GrowingDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HeightProperty.AddOwner(typeof (GrowingDisplay),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnHeightPropertyChanged));
        WidthProperty.AddOwner(typeof (GrowingDisplay),
                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnWidthPropertyChanged));

        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the definition of your RoutedCommand to:

```
private static RoutedUICommand _GrowingOperation;
public static RoutedCommand GrowingOperation
{
    get
    {
        if(_GrowingOperation == null)
        {
            _GrowingOperation = new RoutedUICommand("GrowingOperation", 
                                "GrowingOperation", typeof(WINDOWNAME));
        }
        return _GrowingOperation;
}
```

Then you can clean up your XAML by bringing the Commands class in with:

```
xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE.Commands"
```

Put this in the opening Window tag. (Assuming this is a Window)
Then when you set your command you can use:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="commands:Commands.GrowingOperation"
                Executed="GrowingOperationExecuted"
                CanExecute="GrowingOperationCanExecute"/>
```

My only question is this: How are you implementing `GrowingOperationExecuted` and `GrowingOperationCanExecute`?

Comment: I implement the both methods in the code behind of my `MyUserControl` and then use this usercontrol in my `MainWindow`.

Trying your solution...

Comment: If it doesn't work, would you mind posting `GrowingOperationCanExecute` just to make sure it is implemented correctly?

Comment: Ok. Used your UICommands instead and cleaned up XAML code.
Still not working.
Like said before, the breakpoint in the method doesn't even get executed, but I'll post both methods above.

Comment: You said above that you don't get a hover animation over your context menu? Try running `CommandManager.InvalidateQuerySuggested();` after you populate the ContextMenu.

Also, I noticed that I may have made an error. In the RoutedCommand definition, instead of `typeof(WINDOWNAME)` try `typeof(Commands)`

Comment: Used `typeof(Commands)` already.
`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` like above in edit 2?
Doesn't help...

Comment: FYI: If I remove the command from the `MenuItem` in the `ContextMenu`, the hover effect works again.

Answer (score 0):

This post should be helpful for solving your problem:
http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedCommandsInContextMenu.html.

Comment: Such answers are discouraged. Dont post links to blog posts which contain the answer. YOUR answer should be the last point of research someone has to do.